# Task<T> How to Return

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have the below method which is an implementation of Google.Apis IDatastore

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications:

```
public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
{       
    var account = GetAccountById(key);

    return account;
}
```

The above does not work. I get:

> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'Model.Account' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'*

So I am not sure how to return my `account`. I assume it's something simple but I am not getting there.

Comment: Try to replace <T> with <Model.Account>

Comment: But it's an interface, I must implement it with the anonymous T, right?

Comment: What exactly are you parameterizing?  The method you wrote returns an account, nothing else.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but I am implementing my IDataStore to use with ``Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2``. The default implementation google has stores a file inside %appdata%, but I want to store that information inside a database using Entity Framework.

Comment: Why are you returning a `Task<T>` in the first place?

Comment: What does `GetAccountById()` do? You can create async from sync by wrapping in a `Task`, but if the operation(s) in `GetAccountById()` take long enough to justify doing that (instead of just "task from result"), there's a good chance those operations have async implementations you can use. Then you can make `GetAccountByIdAsync()` method, which you `await` in your `GetAsync<Account>()` method (which in turn can then just be a normal `async` method). Show us more code, so that you can get a good answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

I think correct implementation for `Task<T>` would be something like

```
public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
{
    // Replace with actual logic
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => default(T));
}
```

And for the `Account`

```
public Task<Account> GetAsync(string key)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetAccountById(key));
}
```

Comment: For the first I get : ``Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type 'T' rather than 'Task<T>'``

Comment: I'm not sure about what you suggest, I basically need to put that method returning the correct logic to the ``GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer``

Comment: The question has the missing info: `GetAccountById` returns `Account`: but `GetAsync<T>` needs to be able to return any particular `T`, and cannot be known at compile-time to be related to `Account`. That's unrelated to the use of `Task`, you'd have the same problem with a synchronous `public T Get<T>(string key)` method.

Comment: In .NET 4.5 you could also use Task.Run(() => GetAccountById(key)).  
This is even preferred aboven Task.Factory.StartNew for this case according to: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Comment: This shoud work (with `Task.Run()` or `TaskFactory.StartNew()`, either way) but it would be better to get enough information from the OP so that true async methods are being used here (i.e. rewrite `GetAccountById()` as async, using underlying async methods for whatever I/O, etc. the method is doing).

Comment: You all are free to post an answer.